# Performing multiple paired t-tests by group

Tags: r, group-by, t-test

I have a data frame consisting of 3 groups each of which has multiple pre and post measurements. I would like to run perform paired t-tests for each pre and post measurement for each group.

```
Group| vo2_pre | vo2_post | vt_pre | vt_post 

0       20          20        21        23
1       30          19        10        11
2       10          30        53        34
1       22          25        32        20
2       34          32        40        30
0       30          40        50        40
0       39          19        40        20
1       40          20        20        20
2       50          20        10        10
0       34          30        23        10
```

I can use the code below to get the p-values for pre and post for each group (0, 1, 2) for the vo2 variable. However, I would have to do this multiple times to get the pre and post comparisons for other variables i.e., vt_pre vs vt_post. I have a total of 28 variables (made up of 14 baseline measures and 14 follow up measures).

```
DLR_vo2tt <- DLR_df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do(tidy(t.test(.$vo2_pre, 
                 .$vo2_post, 
                 mu = 0, 
                 alt = "two.sided", 
                 paired = TRUE, 
                 conf.level = 0.99)))
```

My questions: is there a better way to do this so that I don't have to repeat the above code for each of the 14 pre and post pairs of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to reshape your data to a longer format and then running the test. For example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
DLR_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Group, names_to=c("test","stage"), names_sep="_") %>% 
  mutate(stage = factor(stage, levels=c("pre","post"))) %>% 
  group_by(Group, test) %>% 
  summarize(tidy(t.test(value~stage, data=cur_data(), paired=TRUE, conf.level=0.99)))
```

will return

```
  Group test  estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method        alternative
  <int> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      
1     0 vo2       3.5      0.561   0.614         3    -32.9      39.9 Paired t-test two.sided  
2     0 vt       10.2      2.23    0.112         3    -16.6      37.1 Paired t-test two.sided  
3     1 vo2       9.33     1.39    0.298         2    -57.1      75.7 Paired t-test two.sided  
4     1 vt        3.67     0.878   0.473         2    -37.8      45.1 Paired t-test two.sided  
5     2 vo2       4        0.276   0.808         2   -140.      148.  Paired t-test two.sided  
6     2 vt        9.67     1.76    0.220         2    -44.8      64.1 Paired t-test two.sided
```

Comment: This was a great solution, thank you. How can I deal with NAs in the df or implement pairwise deletion? It needs to be paired, but with NAs present I get an error ```! not all arguments have the same length```.  I can't workout how to incorporate ```na.exclude``` or ```generalcorr::napair```.